# javascript functions using forms

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment for school which uses javascript to create functions using forms. I have created the function and does what I need it to do, but to some extent. The function i am creating is to check if a text box follows the constraints i am setting for it using the javascript function. if the user enters a number that is outside of the range, an alert box will show up saying to enter a number between the specified range. I know a lot of people will be using if statements, but i wanted to try a different approach. I am trying with while and do...while statements. I have the function created, but everytime the alert box shows up and i press ok, the alert still keeps showing up. Is there a way from my coding to have it so the alert box does not appear after everytime i click ok?
My code:

```
function checkPrice(formData)
{

 while(!(formData.stickerPrice.value > 0) || (formData.stickerPrice.value < 100000))
 {
    alert("Enter a value between 0 andd 100000");
    setTimeout (function()
    {
        formData.stickerPrice.focus();
    })
 }
}
```

Comment: since you want the alert to happen only "if" certain conditions hold, i don't believe you will be able to avoid having an "if" statement somewhere in your code....

Answer (score 1):

Just change it from `while` to `if`. That way it won't continuously loop. The `while` loop's condition will continue to be `true` until you break away from the Javascript and let the user type something in. The condition will always be `true` once it's entered, since nothing in the condition changes before the next iteration.

Comment: yea, i had already coded it that way. but i was just trying to see if there was another way to code this without using an if statement?

Comment: @bobGlenn I don't think so. The `while`'s condition will always be true since the values never change. You need to let the user type in a new value and then re-evaluate the situation.

Comment: yea, i would like to let the user type in a new value, but the alert box continuously shows up when the user clicks ok

Comment: @bobGlenn Right, so you can't use a `while` loop for something like this. How are you calling `checkPrice` anyways?

Comment: yea, so i guess i will have to use an `if` statement then. Like i said, i wanted to try and code this differently than everyone. i am calling `checkPrice` using the onblur event handler

Comment: @bobGlenn Yeah, unfortunately, this isn't the place/situation to use a `while` loop. Here's an example though: http://jsfiddle.net/vpzbC/1/ . It's all synchronous - the stuff inside the `while` loop waits for the user's input. In your situation, it won't, so you can't use a `while` loop

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you very much for your help. I had a feeling that I was unable to use a while loop, or do..while. I could find find different ways in which to code this so that it would be different than everyone else in the class. Thanks again for your help